# What is the best way to iterate over alternate elements of a Vec in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<usize>` and would like to iterate over all even-numbered elements in it. Basically I would like to understand the ideal Rust equivalent of the following C++ code:

```
const std::vector<uint64_t> vector{1, 4, 9, 16, 25};

for (uint64_t index = 0; index < vector.size(); index += 2) {
    std::cout << vector[index] << std::endl;
}
```

---

This is what I've got so far with `enumerate` and `filter`:

```
let vector: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 4, 9, 16, 25];

// Prints even-indexed numbers from the Vec.
type PredicateType = fn(&(usize, &usize)) -> bool;
let predicate: PredicateType = |&tuple| tuple.0 % 2 == 0;
for tuple in vector.iter().enumerate().filter(predicate) {
    println!("{:?}", tuple.1); // Prints 1, 9, and 25
};
```

This feels a little complex. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Also I see that a tuple is being constructed on every iteration and then discarded on every alternate iteration. This seems inefficient. Is there a way to do this without constructing an intermediate tuple?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [`step_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by) iterator method, which will jump in steps:

```
let vector: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 4, 9, 16, 25];

// Prints even-indexed numbers from the Vec.
for item in vector.iter().step_by(2) {
    println!("{:?}", item); // Prints 1, 9, and 25
}
```

To start at a different index than `0`, combine this with [`skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip):

```
// Prints odd-indexed numbers from the Vec.
for item in vector.iter().skip(1).step_by(2) {
    println!("{:?}", item); // Prints 4, 16
}
```

[(Rust playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20vector%3A%20Vec%3Cusize%3E%20%3D%20vec!%5B1%2C%204%2C%209%2C%2016%2C%2025%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Prints%20even-indexed%20numbers%20from%20the%20Vec.%0A%20%20%20%20for%20item%20in%20vector.iter().step_by(2)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20item)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Prints%201%2C%209%2C%20and%2025%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Prints%20odd-indexed%20numbers%20from%20the%20Vec.%0A%20%20%20%20for%20item%20in%20vector.iter().skip(1).step_by(2)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20item)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Prints%204%2C%2016%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`step_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by):

```
let data = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

for x in data.iter().step_by(2) {
    println!("{}", x)
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
```